# react-native ScrollView does not render the whole list

Tags: listview, react-native, scrollview

I'm working on React-Native app. I use components of  Native-base library and I need the ListView to render hundreds of items, vertically. When I set `flexDirection` of ScrollView to `row`, ListView renders all items without any problem horizontally. But, when I set it to `column`, it renders only small portion - 11 of them. I hope there is someone can help me to figure out what is happening and what is the problem with `column` type of rendering. What is unclear for me is, on `column` type rendering, `ListView` does not limit items with the size of screen, it is scrollable, but only for 11 items.

here is the inside of `Container`.

```
<Container>
                    <Header style={{"backgroundColor": '#00FFFF',elevation: 0}}>
                        <Body style={{flex: 4}}>
                        <Text style={{letterSpacing: 0.5,color: 'white'}}>Whobees</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </Header>
                    <View style={{flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                        <ScrollView style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                            <ListView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', left: 5}}
                              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                              enableEmptySections={true}
                              horizontal
                              renderRow={(rowData)=>this.renderRow(rowData)}>
                            </ListView>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
</Container>
```

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful!

Comment: ListView already has a ScrollView inside it. Yours is unnecessary and should work if removed